# Getting the location of the generated file by Compiler API

Tags: java, compilation

How could I get the location (Path) of the `.class` file which has been generated by Compiler API? I.e The file is compiled by `CompilationTask.call()`

Here's the code:

```
JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();

DiagnosticCollector<JavaFileObject> diagnostics = new DiagnosticCollector<>();

StandardJavaFileManager manager = compiler.getStandardFileManager(diagnostics, null, null);

File file = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/target/classes/tmp/" +"FileName.java");

Iterable<String> options = Arrays
            .asList(new String[] { "-d", System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/target/classes/" });

Iterable<? extends JavaFileObject> sources = manager.getJavaFileObjectsFromFiles(Arrays.asList(file));

CompilationTask task = compiler.getTask(null, manager, diagnostics, options, null, sources);

task.call();

manager.close();
```

Comment: You are telling the compiler to write to `${user.dir}/target/classes/`. Aren't they there?

Comment: @Marvin Yes, They are there, But I'm seeking for a potential method of Compiler API which returns the full location path of a successfully compiled file (instead of the boolean value that `call()` method returns)